# Is it possible to send webcamera screenshot to Blazor C# from Javascript at a fast rate (1 screenshot every 15 ms)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I need to take screenshots from a webcamera and send them to Blazor webassemly for processing. We have some C# code that does some image recognition and I do not want to translate that code to javascript.

I need to process a frame at least every 15 ms. The problem is that when I run JSRuntime.InvokeAsync to get the base64 data, the webcamera starts to lag, and I am only able to send a screenshot every 1 second or so.

Is it possible to do this in Blazor?

Blazor backend code:

```
while(true) {
var base64string = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("WebCamFunctions.snap");
// do processing of image
await Task.Delay(15);
}
```

FrontEnd javascript:

```
function snap() {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    return data;
}
```

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL` takes a screenshot of the element and serializes it, it doesn't retrieve images from a web cam. The serialized image will be serialized (marshalled) into JSON by Blazor, which is already a slow process. You can use [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) instead, to avoid the first serialization. To avoid marshalling through JSON you need to use [Unmarshalled JS Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#unmarshalled-js-interop)

Comment: Check [Optimizing JS Interop in a Blazor WebAssembly application](https://www.meziantou.net/optimizing-js-interop-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm) and [Generating and efficiently exporting a file in a Blazor WebAssembly application](https://www.meziantou.net/generating-and-downloading-a-file-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm)

Comment: Do you have an example of sending toBlob to Blazor and consume it as byte []. BINDING.js_to_mono_obj is always null